# Xamarin IOS UICollectionView search result by section

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView working with a search bar.
When the client search for something, the algorithm sort the cell by 2 category.

The first results, a separator line, the second results

I found in the UICollectionView some functions about section but there is no documentation at all about them.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a sample for you, a simple UICollectionView with a search bar, and you can search with it. The result will be separated to 2 groups as you wish.

[UICollectionViewSample](https://github.com/lwnwowone/UICollectionViewSample)

Hope it can help you.

Comment: wow thank you really, i can't wait to try it when i get home. Since i posted my question i found out how to have section but not how to display a line between the two. Does your project include the separator line? I am really new to xamarin but i have 5 years of experience with c# and i find the lack of documentation really frustrating. Doing something as simple as adding section should not require hours of googling and search in the vast undocumented framework.

Comment: I am now able to do animations with the built-in xamarin animation system but the hit box of buttons does not follow and once again i have to browse the whole web to only find some Xcode thing that maybe could be converted. If you also have a quickfix for that i would really owe you one.

Comment: You are right, Xamarin's documentation is really not friendly enough, if you want to use it make an app, I suggest you learning at least one of Objective-C or Swift, then you can find the native way to solve your issue and convert it to C#. And about the problem about animation, I don't get the point, could you just describe it more clearly? It's better to have some screen shot or .GIF, then I must can help you.

Comment: i found the answer for the button. after an animation the button hit box do not follow. i have to use autolayout after the animation. Really a design flaw. After reading a lot of stackoverflow answer for my problem i started understanding the strange syntax of objective C, solved a few problem by converting it. Anyway thank you for your time.